# SQL query and output in PHP does not work - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: mysql, sql, output, internal-server-error

i try to put a working SQL query in a PHP-file for my Cronjob. But i receive only a blank 500 Internal Server Error notification.

The SQL query works fine in PHPmyAdmin.

Here the code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("HOST","DBUSER","DBPW","DBNAME");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT oc_order_product.order_id AS bestellnr, oc_order_product.quantity, oc_order_product.model, oc_order_product.name, oc_order.shipping_company, oc_order.shipping_firstname, oc_order.shipping_lastname, oc_order.shipping_city
FROM oc_order_product, oc_order
WHERE oc_order.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id
AND oc_order.order_status_id = 1
ORDER BY bestellnr, model");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['oc_order_product.order_id'] . "; " . $row['oc_order_product.quantity'] "; " . $row['oc_order_product.model'] "; " . $row['oc_order_product.name'] "; " . $row['oc_order.shipping_company'] "; " . $row['oc_order.shipping_firstname'] "; " . $row['oc_order.shipping_lastname'] "; " . $row['oc_order.shipping_city']; //these are the fields that you have stored in your database table
      echo "<br />";
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

The error_log is empty. Is something wrong with my code? 
The error message, that i receive via mail ist:

Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Any idea?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I can note that this is incorrect:

```
$row['oc_order_product.order_id']
```

The row has no column with that name.  In fact, you have explicitly given the column the name `bestellnr`.  So, you might try:

```
$row['bestellnr']
```

I can't guarantee that is the only problem, though.

Comment: Fantastic. Probably ist was this. I found other little errors and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's the final code:

```
    <?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=DBHOST;dbname=DBNAME', 'DBUSER', 'DBPW');

$sql = "SELECT oc_order_product.order_id AS bestellnr, oc_order_product.quantity, oc_order_product.model, oc_order_product.name, oc_order.shipping_company, oc_order.shipping_firstname, oc_order.shipping_lastname, oc_order.shipping_city
FROM oc_order_product, oc_order
WHERE oc_order.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id
AND oc_order.order_status_id = 1
ORDER BY bestellnr, model";

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo $row['bestellnr']."; ".$row['quantity']."; ".$row['model']."; ".$row['name']."; ".$row['shipping_company']."; ".$row['shipping_firstname']."; ".$row['shipping_lastname']."; ".$row['shipping_city']."<br />";
}

?>
```